# How does glPolygonOffset work internally?

Tags: math, opengl, shader, render, depth

I'm trying to understand how glPolygonOffset works from the inside. After researching, I found this formula:

`o = m * factor + r * units`

but I don't understand how the "m" parameter (depth bias factor) is calculated.

It is clear that `m = max(|dz/dx|, |dz/dy|)`, where dz/dx and dz/dy are the derivatives of the depth value with respect to the x and y coordinates of the polygon in screen space.

But I don't understand at all how to calculate `dx, dy, dz`. Can you explain to me what formulas and parameters are needed to calculate these values?

Comment: dz/dx is a derivative and dz/dy is also a derivative

Comment: @user253751 I know that it is derivative, but how to calculate these values programmatically? I mean it can be approximal formula (f(x0 + h) - f(x0)) / h, but how to find x0, h values?

Comment: well that would be the specific pixel where you are talking about. x0 can be any pixel and h is 1-pixel distance - that is how the GPU usually calculates derivatives. Or perhaps it is the same for the whole triangle (depends which z it is using) in which case it might calculate it one time for the whole triangle

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it makes more sense to me now. But one more question. Since dx, dy are 1-pixel distance, then what is max function for, if dx/dz and dy/dz will have the same result?

Comment: I guess you don't know what a derivative is. dz/dy means how much the z changes if you go 1 pixel up or down. dz/dx means how much the z changes if you go 1 pixel left or right